# Testing an angular service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

This might be a really silly question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

I want to unit test a service that for now has two simple operations:

```
angular.module('transaction').factory('Transaction',
    function() {
        var transactionList = [];

        // Public API
        return {
            addTransaction: function(transaction) {
                transactionList.push(transaction);
            },
            getTransactions: function(){
                return transactionList;
            }
        };
    }
);
```

### Tests

Now in my tests I want to test if the service's `addTransaction` and `getTransactions` methods work, but I'm not really sure how to do it properly, because what I'm doing right now is using the other method to test the first, e.g:

```
it('should be able to return an array of transactions', function() {
    //add new transaction
    var trans = {id: 1, value: test};
    Transaction.addTransaction(trans);

    //test get      
    var result = Transaction.getTransactions();

    expect(Array.isArray(result)).toBe(true);
    expect(result).toEqual([trans]);
});

it('should be able to add a transaction', function(){
    var trans = {id: 1, value: test};
    Transaction.addTransaction(trans);

    var result = Transaction.getTransactions();

    expect(result).toEqual([trans]);
});
```

I expect these methods to become more complex, but what I wanted to do would be to have a way to test one of the methods without having to use the other. It would be great if anyone could point me to an example of some tests for operations similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways for testing these independently:

1) make transactionList publicly available:

```
Transaction.addTransaction(trans);
expect(Transaction.transactionList).toEqual([trans]);
```

2) return transactionList in both methods

```
 expect(Transaction.addTransaction(trans)).toEqual([trans]);
```

I would go with the second solution, as you can keep transactionList private.

Comment: Thanks, option 2 seems like what I should do.